# display wordpress user who published a pending post of another user

Tags: sort, dashboard, publish, columns

I have a custom post type, when I view my posts of this type in the dashboard I see:
Title   Author  Date Added  as well as a few more I have added

My question is how can I display (like the author column) the user which approved/published the post

Ideally I would like to be able to click on the name and view the publishers published posts

```
function my_manage_product_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
global $post;

switch( $column ) {


    case 'publisher' :

        $publisher = get_the_modified_author();

    $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'genre' => $term->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
            esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'genre', 'display' ) )
           )
        echo $link;

    break;

    /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
    default :
    break;
}
}

add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_product_columns', 10, 2 );
```

I found an example online sorting by genre but I don't know how to modify it (what to replace the variables with)

```
'genre' => $term->slug 
 $term->name
 $term->term_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_modified_author();` isn't going to tell you who published the post, just who last edited it. You will need to capture you publisher yourself.

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
  $publisher = wp_get_current_user();
  update_post_meta($ID,'my_publisher',$publisher);

}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Then use `get_post_meta($post_id,'my_publisher')` to retrieve the data.

Of course there are a numerous ways to fine tune this. Do you want to only save the publisher the first time it is published, in those cases where that can occur? Etc.

Comment: My question is more directed towards making this authors name click-able to show all the posts they modified. For the part that you answered I would rather not use custom fields as they can be modified. Can I get a list of authors from the revisions??